# Running update-manager -d prompts to install 'Focal Fossa' development release. How can I force upgrade to the official non-development release

Tags: upgrade, lts, 20.04

I'm currently running 18.04 LTS. 
I'd like to upgrade my existing machine to 20.04 LTS.  If I enter sudo update-manager -d in the terminal, it finds an updated release (20.04).  When I proceed with the installation the release notes that appear on screen indicate this is still a development release.

Is there a way I can run update-manager -d so it updates and points to the non-development branch release of 20.04?  Or do I simply have to wait?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @user535733 I appreciate the link. I believe this answers my question